# ssrs Summing two fields same dataset, different tablix

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to sum two same fields, from two different Tablix's.
Both Tablix's filter for different building names. "Mydata" is the  name of my dataset.

`=Sum(Fields!TotalFloorArea.Value,"Mydata") +Sum(Fields!TotalFloorArea.Value, "Mydata")`

How do I reference the different Tablix?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to accomplish this.  One approach is to use an `IIf()` as part of each of your `SUM()` calls.  Using the `IIf()` condition(s) you will be repeating the condition(s) used to filter your two Tablix controls.

Try something like this:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!BuildingName.Value = "BLDG-A", 
         Fields!TotalFloorArea.Value, 
         0), "Mydata") +
 Sum(IIf( Fields!BuildingName.Value = "BLDG-B", 
         Fields!TotalFloorArea.Value, 
         0), "Mydata")
```

I prefer to use Report Variables for this.  Define a couple of report variables `totalBuildingA` and `totalBuidlingB` and use the expressions above for the individual variable's expressions:

*totalBuildingA*

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!BuildingName.Value = "BLDG-A", 
         Fields!TotalFloorArea.Value, 
         0), "Mydata")
```

*totalBuildingB*

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!BuildingName.Value = "BLDG-B", 
         Fields!TotalFloorArea.Value, 
         0), "Mydata")
```

Then you can add the two report variables together to get the equivalent result as the first example, (but with code that is a lot more flexibile for combining the SUMs for two or more other Building Names etc):

```
=Variables!totalBuildingA.Value + Variables!totalBuildingB.Value
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply! To add to my problem. The first Tablix- it filters for 25 buildings, the second tablix only filters for 1 building.                         I will then have to copy this formula for other fields.

Comment: how do I sum with multiple conditions?

Comment: In that case you want an alternate approach.  I bet you can find a post here that explains it.  In short: you add a totals row to each of your Tablix controls and add then simple `SUM()` expressions on the appropriate column to each Tablix as well.  Then careful name the textbox controls that contain the `SUM()` total value in each tablix: THEN you can reference the values of these textboxes for your 'grand totals'.  You can also ultimately hide the total row if desired. Then the conditionals are expressed only once, in the FILTER of each Tablix.  Look around -- you'll find examples like this.

Comment: By the way -- Welcome to StackOverflow  #SOReadyToHelp

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work now. I added a row Outside the group below then added Totals into Rows. Then for grand total I referenced the textboxes for example Reportitems!Textbox22 + Reportitems!Textbox23.

I'm not sure this makes sense. But now working! Just trying to work out the final formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to textboxes can get messy. And there's no direct way to reference sums from other groups or tables. A good option that will work for this is to add calculated fields to your dataset. You can have one for the 1 building value and another for the other 25 buildings. The expression would look something like this:

```
    =IIf(Fields!BuildingName.Value = "BLDG-A", Fields!TotalFloorArea.Value, Nothing)
```

That way you can sum those calculated fields from anywhere in the report. You don't need to specify the scope in your Sum function, let it use the current scope for the cell like this:

```
    =Sum(Fields!BldgA_TotalFloorArea.Value)
```